# Editing scripts outside (online) Code Editor?

Tags: google-earth-engine

While reading EE docs https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground, something called my attention:

"Repositories can be accessed using Git, so you can manage and edit your scripts outside the Code Editor..."

I use EE online editor and I'm aware of possibilities git bring (I think). But I'm wondering in which circumstances it might be useful to be able to "...edit your scripts outside the Code Editor..."? I guess Code Editor mean the online one.

I understand, outside the online code editor the scripts might be edited as any file. But I cannot run/test them, at least not before uploading them back to EE. So I'll be doing some kind of blind changes. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://github.com/gee-community/ee-runner

Comment: You can also use the Python API, and to visualize your results you can use [geetools](https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools)

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine scripts owned by user accounts are browsable online at https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME/ (if the account used to view the page has sufficient permissions to view the repository).

The scripts are stored in a Git repository can be cloned and manipulated similarly to other Git repositories.

```
git clone https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME/REPO_NAME
```

One possible reason for wanting to clone and edit scripts outside of the Earth Engine Code Editor may be to make bulk changes (such as Comment/Documentation edits) to a large collection of scripts.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the place to make this comment. I'm imagining to work with EE in a (let me call it) detached  head mode where I have two windows, one with the map and another is SublimeText (or whatever else, Vim would be cool as well). So I could do fast edit on the text editor I'm used to. I'm used to `Ctrl+B` to build. I think EE online editor is easy to access and is definitely the place to start. But it gets difficult when I want to see multiple files at same time.